# Eclipse ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

Everything works fined, but suddenly eclipse stopped execute and junit tests or even main method, when i run them using run as - > Java application, run as ->  junit test

It simply throws error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.ClassName
```

whene ClassName - is class from where i trying to run method main. 
It affect only one of my projects ... Different workspaces works fine, other project in same workspace works fine as well.

I'm sure if i recreate current project, error will gone. But the adjustments of this project in eclipse is really hard, so i want to avoid it.

Any clue?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is looking at your .project file and compare it with other projects to see what got corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out.  The problem was with installed JRE in eclipse setting. I was playing around with this setting and changed installed JRE to JDK, and for some reason it broke the eclipse project.

Answer (score 2):

The `ClassName` is not in the Class Path, if you start from console you should use `-cp` parameter , if from eclipse, please add `ClassName` to the sources of current(start) project.

Comment: This question is not about classPath, this question is about eclipse settings. If you read my question, you should understand, that ClassName - is class from where i trying to run method main. So of course it is already in sources of current projects.

Comment: @aauser, if you receiving exception like this it means that this class is not in sources, and you did not understand what did I write! Check your eclipse/project settings (Java Build Path/Source).

Comment: This class was created in package that was in source folder in current project. Other classes, like JUnit tests was created before and was in source folder as well. All of them was broken, but i still was able to find them using crtl-alt-T, refactor etc. Anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **adarshr**, I was able to look at the *Problems window* and determine that the build was failing because it could not find a class I had written.

I had used the **MS TFS plugin** to create a "**shelveset**" and it was supposed to have removed my pending changes in the process.  However, this integration with the TFS snapin and Eclipse is obviously not well implemented, since the Eclipse project still thought the file existed and was complaining that it could not be compiled.

I went and manually deleted those "files" or "non-existing files" from the Eclipse project (that I thought I had removed with the shelveset action) and the problem was solved.

Also....

Another annoying things is that the Tomcat error I was getting by trying to debug within Eclipse was like this:

> SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class
>   com.CompanyName.ProjectName.servlet.StartupConfigListener
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.CompanyName.ProjectName.servlet.StartupConfigListener     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)

In reality, there was no problem at all with StartupConfigListener.java!!  The build failed due to the OTHER problems I mentioned above, and therefore I guess this was the first class it attempted to load and failed....  because the entire project hadn't been able to compile perhaps?

(Here's to hoping my next project is using Visual Studio instead of Eclipse!)

Answer (score -1):

You can also try going back to the basics.  Check your command line and VM args.  I've had this situation where a VM arg I was passing in was a path to a file that had a space in the path, and I had forgotten to include the full path in quotes.  So e.g., if my arg looked something like

```
-DFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\myfile
```

...I'd get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError caused by a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.